# China GDP Data - Base year

Tags: macroeconomics, gdp, china, base-year

I had been searching for the GDP data of China and finally found it [here](https://www.frbatlanta.org/cqer/research/china-macroeconomy.aspx?panel=1).

The dataset gives the log real GDP data from 1992 (annual, quarterly and monthly). It doesn't specify the base year of the data, all it says is 
"*Implicit price deflator for GDP by value added, 1992Q1-*", for the GDP deflator. Is there a way to find the base year for the real GDP data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this paper](https://www.frbatlanta.org/-/media/documents/research/publications/wp/2016/07.pdf), page 8, it says

> Quarterly seasonally adjusted nominal GDP and its deflator
>   are constructed by Higgins and Zha (2015).

That paper can be found [here](https://78462f86-a-8b021025-s-sites.googlegroups.com/a/tzha.net/www/articles/ChinaTimeSeries_HZ2.pdf?attachauth=ANoY7crFfZNi20fLtE-gnF4Ypnp8aXbf_rOBho_pqNs1vZvReSyMdPeKbvodC3-kwk4zZW__ViCGZAx16zLtfbjFW_ZYbD4b4BLJPgbIUFOUMrTPabGZGwSYx7vKqbk_oejIaAxxvrMlwQW5i-tuEqmFKBXNExaZj7oGuh4uDXgVPUl2El5luRJ0g85WJfw5fZo49-UCsfyuDGA6zBJagCjYv0b5Nq_y2w%3D%3D&attredirects=0) (google did not help to find this paper. I had to look for the personal website of one of the authors, [here](http://www.tzha.net/articles#CHINADATA)).

This document states in section II.1, Step 1:

> Annual
>   real GDP-va –
>   RGDP_va_A
>   – is set to
>   NGDP_va_A
>   in 2008 ...

This is confirmed later in the next page, when they say:

> Except for the base year (chosen to be 2008) ...

So it seems to be 2008.